# Postfix - SMTP Port 25

Tags: postfix

I need to use port 25 to send some notifications on local networks (nagios, ups etc) without sasl authentication.

So I have to block access from net to use port 25

I added to smtp master and its working,

```
smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
```

but when somebody sends email from outside (587/465) get error

```
Client host rejected: Access denied
```

Why ?

Maybe there is a different way to do that

```
    # ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy

smtp     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtp
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,defer_unauth_destination
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
#  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth

submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,defer_unauth_destination
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth

smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,defer_unauth_destination
#  -  smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
#628       inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o syslog_name=postfix/$service_name
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
postlog   unix-dgram n  -       n       -       1       postlogd
#
```

Answer (score 1):

A standard Postfix configuration allows both receiving mail from outside as well as sending from local "trusted" hosts/networks over port 25 without authentication. You don't need to mess up with `smtpd_client_restrictions`, the defaults are pretty reasonable. The default values of all `smtpd_*_restrictions` are empty except from `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, which is:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```

and that does exactly what you need. `permit_mynetworks` allows mail from hosts specified by `mynetworks` parameter, and `rejest_unauth_destination` rejects all mail whose recipient is not local (that is, the recipient domain matches `mydestination`, `inet_interfaces`, `proxy_interfaces`, `virtual_alias_domains`, `virtual_mailbox_domains` or `relay_domains`).

In simple cases like yours, the only parameters you would care about are `mydestination` which should list all possible names under which your server can receive mail and `mynetworks` that should include IP addresses of all hosts/networks that are allowed to send mail without authentication.

I suggest that you start configuring Postfix from very simple, but working configurations and gradually add more complicated things. A good place to start is http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html which shows most typical configurations. In your case, "Postfix on a local network" is the one that may interest you.

And, it is a good practice to not mess up your `master.cf` with too many unneeded `-o` parameters. Instead, `main.cf` is the intended place to put your configuration. In simple Postfix instances `master.cf` usually can be left at factory default.

Also the useful commands are `postconf -d` which lists **default values** of all Postfix configuration parameters and `postconf -n` which lists configuration parameters that you **explicitly specified** in `main.cf` (they may be identical or different from the defaults).